# How to check if a checkbox is selected in Selenium WebDriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please find the code below

```
element = WAIT.until{driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='graphs']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/label")}

element.selected?
element.click
element.selected? == false
```

I tried in Irb `element.selected`?
It returns false even if checkbox is checked.

How to check this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selected?` should be working for Options, checkboxes, and radio buttons. But a safer method could be to look at the checked property yourself:

```
element.attribute("checked") #false
element.click
element.attribute("checked") #true
```

As for why `selected?` isn't working, is the box appearing checked after the WebDriver clicked? I would assume you have some JavaScript interfering  with your actual click, or perhaps you're handling the wrong object on accident. Judging by the xPath you're using, it's possible you accidentally found the wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to find a label. I assume you are wanting to select an `input` or something that might be next to your label, check your xpath. (labels cannot be selected.)